# UFW block internet connection while using proxychains, How could I configure UFW?

Tags: server, firewall, ufw

I downloaded Tor, I edited proxychains.conf, uncommented dynamic_chain, proxy DNS - no leak for DNS data, proxy DNS. I added at the end of the proxychains.config file 5 different socks5 server IPs and port numbers like the example in the end of the proxychains.config file. Now if I type into the terminal: `proxychains firefox https://duckduckgo.com` I can use the internet and browser and everything is perfect, but if I enable UFW I don't have internet and there is a question mark instead of the wifi symbol.

What's the problem with the UFW? I tried to add rule to UFW to open those ports and proxy servers IP addresses I added to the end of the proxychains. config file, but if I enable UFW I still don't have internet and connection.

How can I make UFW able to work together with proxychains? Isn't it possible maybe to use UFW and proxychains at the same time? If I disable UFW is it a major risk? Is there any other firewall that I can configure to work together with proxychains?